# Initialization of a pointer to an array of int

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, initialization, int

I have been mucking around with C++ once again and noticed a strange behavior regarding the initialization of an array when declared as a pointer inside a class member method or inside the `main()` function.

```
int * p = new int[20];
```

What I would expect to happen is that the pointers will remain uninitialized with random values as they do with

```
int arr[20];
```

But instead they are all zeroed. What is going on?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. `p` is a pointer, not an array. Also, `p` blatantly has an initializer. (But `*p` doesn't.)

Comment: As an aside: most of the time, you shouldn't be using a raw pointer *or* an array or `new []` (you usually want `std::vector`).

Comment: @Cz-David Most operating systems will clear out the memory allocated to your program, so that you cannot peek on what the previous program did. That's a possible reason for seeing a lot of zeros.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though they're zero (this is loosely put, see below), they're not initialized.

Actually, you can't tell they're zero, because if you read the values, you run into undefined behavior. You can't read an un-initialized variable.

To have the array value-initialized, you can do:

```
int * p = new int[20]();
//                   ^^
//             note parenthesis
```

but otherwise no, it's not initialized.

Comment: I know how to initialize an array. I just would have expected for an uninitialized array to be not zeroes. Am I to take it that the compiler (g++) defines the undefined behavior as zeroes (and I also know I should not depend on that). It just doesn't behave as I have expected.

Comment: @Cz-David: Think about where the memory for a dynamic allocation comes from, and think about how an operating system hands out memory. Keep in mind that more than one person may be using an operating system at a time.

Comment: @Cz-David no, don't assume anything. You could just as well not have zeroes there. The OS just gives you memory - if that memory was used before and it was 0, it won't change it. If it gives you memory that was used and set to something else, it will be that...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Actually, modern OSes that give you entirely *new* memory *do* usually zero out the entire page for security reasons. You wouldn't want your own data end up in a different process space by accident, would you?

Comment: @KerrekSB well, I wouldn't say that to a beginner, as not to leave the impression that he can rely on this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a pointer to an integer, and it is initialized with the result of a `new[]` expression. That expression returns the address of the first element of a dynamically allocated array of integers. The array itself is not initialized and contains indeterminate values. If you had said `new int[100]()`, the array would have been zero-initialized instead.